# Data Loader > Edit SOQL query for Extraction > using AND & OR in the conditions = Not working

Tags: soql, data-loader, error

I'm Using Dataloader to Export. In the SOQL Query, I can't seem to use "AND" & "OR" all in one Query. Only one or the other.

```
Select ID, ParentId, RecordTypeId, OwnerId FROM Account 
WHERE Active_Client__c = TRUE 
AND ParentId = null 
AND RecordTypeId = '0111xxxxxxxxxxxxx' AND 
AccountId = '0011111xxxxxxxxxx' OR
AccountId = '0011111xxxxxxxxxx' OR
AccountId = '0011111xxxxxxxxxx' OR
AccountId = '0011111xxxxxxxxxx' OR
AccountId = '0011111xxxxxxxxxx' OR
AccountId = '0011111xxxxxxxxxx' OR
AccountId = '0011111xxxxxxxxxx'
```

Getting This Error:

[image]

Please help & Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the Edit Sebas, I have no idea how to do that.

Comment: Here's the [formatting guide](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/editing-help)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than writing a series of `OR` clauses, use an `IN` clause to match many potential Ids.

```
Select ID, ParentId, RecordTypeId, OwnerId 
FROM Account 
WHERE Active_Client__c = TRUE 
      AND ParentId = null 
      AND RecordTypeId = '0111xxxxxxxxxxxxx' 
      AND AccountId IN ('0011111xxxxxxxxxx', '0011111xxxxxxxxxx', '0011111xxxxxxxxxx', ...)
```

You shouldn't switch between `OR` and `AND` without grouping using parentheses; even if it works, it makes it much harder to reason about your Boolean logic because you're relying on implicit operator precedence.

Using `IN` simplifies and clarifies your query logic.

Comment: Oh... So by saying "AND AccountID IN ( '2222' , '3333' , '4444')", the data inside of the Parentheses = OR?

Comment: Roughly, yes. It is `true` if the Account Id is any of the values in the parenthesis.

Comment: Much Love Sir. Thank you for being smart!